# Local TCP connections. Why do they exist?

Tags: networking, tcp, netstat

My understanding of TCP is - it's a 4th layer protocol responsible for transporting packets from one "machine" to a destination "machine".

However, when I do a netstat -a command in my system without an active internet connection, I still see so many TCP connections which are established. I am unable to understand why do we have TCP connections in established state even when I don't have an internet connection?

My basics are not that strong. I am looking for a conceptual answer of my question. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think we do have something called ports which are used for connecting applications to applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding of TCP is - it's a 4th layer protocol responsible for transporting packets from one "machine" to a destination "machine".

TCP is a communication protocol for **applications** not for machines. It does not matter if the applications are on different machines or on the same machine. Typical use cases where local communication is done are connections between some application and a local database server, between a reverse proxy and the local web application etc, between application and a local printer spooler, ...

Comment: Okay. So my understanding was wrong. Can I say that http, the 7th layer protocol does a stateful or stateless connection to different "machines" with the help of TCP connections

Comment: @Chandeep: No. Take my example of *"... between a reverse proxy and the local web application ..."*. In this case HTTP is spoken between two local applications. *".. the 7th layer protocol does a stateful or stateless connection ..."* - HTTP does no connections, but TCP (4th layer) does. And TCP connections are always stateful. HTTP itself is not stateful though.

Comment: I meant to say http. Not 7th layer protocol. Sorry. Got it.

Comment: So are you saying that HTTP is still spoken between a local node js server that I have created with a database application even though I don't have an Internet connection?

Comment: @Chandeep: The local nodejs server might speak a database specific protocol to the database, i.e. not HTTP.  But it still might be a local TCP connection. But a nodejs server is usually not directly exposed to the outside network, but there is a reverse proxy like nginx in front. Between the nginx and the nodejs server HTTP is spoken, locally.